# Postfix does not send mails until the service is restarted

Tags: postfix

When I restart my server, postfix starts up - I can verify this by doing `postfix status`.  It says "the Postfix mail system is up and running."  When I try to send an email from a PHP script after that, however, it does not get sent, but just sits in the mail queue.  I can verify this by typing `mailq`, which shows the message that should have been sent.  If I restart *postfix*, not the server, by running `postfix stop` then `postfix start`, within 30 seconds to a minute the emails are delivered.  Why do I have to restart postfix in order for it to work properly?

Here is my /etc/postfix/main.cf file with all comments stripped out.

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = myhostname.mydomain.com #I actually have my real domain on my server entered here
mydomain = mydomain.com.com #I have the real domain on my server
myorigin = $myhostname
inet_interfaces = $myhostname
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/README_FILES
```

and for commmand `postconf -n`:

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = $myhostname
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mydomain = domain.com # real domain replaced for anonymity
myhostname = host.domain.com #real was taken out
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: What's the configuration of postfix?

Comment: What do you mean by that?  I don't know a whole lot about postfix, is there a specific setting I might need to look at.

Comment: How do you configured postfix? Did you follow a guide or you asked someone else? What's your main.cf file content? What's the output of `postfinger`?

Comment: Have you considered looking at your logs?

Comment: People here will be able to help only if you provide your postfix configuration `postconf -n` and log lines from postfix (redacting any sensitive information,of course )

Comment: @Braiam, I have added the configuration file.  See anything that might be causing the issue?

Comment: ...and the relevant part(s) of the log files?

Comment: @roaima There is no log! (I would have checked if there was one) Looked in /var/log, and there is no `maillog` folder`.  Do need to install rsyslog for postfix?

Comment: There is a maillog file that is empty though.

Comment: Are you using Debian? Can you post the output of `service postfix status` when the server is NOT sending email (before the restart). I've seen similar behavior when postfix can't bind to the network addresses after a system reboot (because it starts before the network is ready). Restarting postfix fixes it because the network it working properly thus postfix can bind at that time.

Comment: @TCB13, I think you had the solution!  I found another page that had this code: `/sbin/chkconfig --level 345 postfix on` which I think fixed the run level which may have caused it to start before the network.  Anyways, that fixed it.

Comment: @user3413723 that seems specific to your case (or some cases). I did a very detailed analysis of my boot (because I also had issues with other programs) and the issue seems to be related to the network-online target. I've extensively documented this here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245635/systemd-networking-ipv6-networking-not-available-at-boot and here https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2037. Looks like `systemd-networkd-wait-online` doesn't wait for IPv6 addresses to come up, it just waits for IPv4.