# Systemd networking: IPv6 networking not available at boot

Tags: networking, boot, systemd, ipv6

I've a Debian machine running multiple static IPv4 and IPv6 addresses managed by `systemd` itself at `/etc/systemd/network/10-static-eth0.network` as follows:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Address=2a04:----::149/64
Address=2a04:----::242/64
Address=2a04:----::243/64
Gateway=2a04:----:0001

Address=5.----.149/25
Address=5.----.242/25
Address=5.----.243/25
Gateway=5.----.129

DNS=89.----.4
DNS=46.----.104
```

I've multiple processes that start with the system via `systemd` units like OpenVPN, Bind9 etc. They're all set to bind to specific IPs of the interface `eth0`. However they fail to start because they can't bind to the `IPv6` addresses after boot.

**How do I know this?**

I made two test units that use `ping` and `ping6` to test the network right after the targets `network.target` and `network-online.target` and this happens:

IPv4 Test Result:

```
server.example:~# systemctl status abootping.service
● abootping.service - A boot-time ping for network testing
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/abootping.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2015-11-26 11:01:58 CET; 45s ago
 Main PID: 433 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 26 11:01:54 server.example ping[433]: PING test-ping-host.example (89.-----.8) from 5.----.149 : 56(84) bytes of data.
Nov 26 11:01:54 server.example ping[433]: 64 bytes from test-ping-host.example (89.-----.8): icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=4.92 ms
Nov 26 11:01:55 server.example ping[433]: 64 bytes from test-ping-host.example (89.-----.8): icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=4.92 ms
Nov 26 11:01:56 server.example ping[433]: 64 bytes from test-ping-host.example (89.-----.8): icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=4.84 ms
Nov 26 11:01:57 server.example ping[433]: 64 bytes from test-ping-host.example (89.-----.8): icmp_seq=4 ttl=59 time=5.41 ms
Nov 26 11:01:58 server.example ping[433]: 64 bytes from test-ping-host.example (89.-----.8): icmp_seq=5 ttl=59 time=4.95 ms
Nov 26 11:01:58 server.example ping[433]: --- test-ping-host.example ping statistics ---
Nov 26 11:01:58 server.example ping[433]: 5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4007ms
Nov 26 11:01:58 server.example ping[433]: rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.843/5.010/5.414/0.209 ms
```

IPv6 Test Result:

```
server.example:~# systemctl status abootping6.service
● abootping6.service - A boot-time ping6 for network testing
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/abootping6.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-11-26 11:01:54 CET; 56s ago
 Main PID: 436 (code=exited, status=2)

Nov 26 11:01:54 server.example ping6[436]: ping: bind icmp socket: Cannot assign requested address
Nov 26 11:01:54 server.example systemd[1]: abootping6.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Nov 26 11:01:54 server.example systemd[1]: Failed to start A boot-time ping6 for network testing.
Nov 26 11:01:54 server.example systemd[1]: Unit abootping6.service entered failed state.
```

As you can see the IPv4 is working perfectly after boot, however IPv6 isn't and all boot processes that need IPv6 fail do bind.

---

**About my `network-online.target`**

In order to really make sure my boot units only start after the network is really working I added `After=network.target network-online.target` to all of them.

`network-online.target` itself has this `wants`:

[image]

That includes:

```
[Unit]
Description=Wait for Network to be Configured
Documentation=man:systemd-networkd-wait-online.service(8)
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=shutdown.target
Requisite=systemd-networkd.service
After=systemd-networkd.service
Before=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=network-online.target
```

According to [documentation](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-networkd-wait-online.service.html):

> systemd-networkd-wait-online is a one-shot system service that waits
>   for the network to be configured. By default, it will wait for all
>   links it is aware of and which are managed by
>   systemd-networkd.service(8) to be fully configured or failed, and for
>   at least one link to gain a carrier.

The real effect of this service wait is noticeable on boot, and my test `ping` services respect it:

[image]

---

**The `ping` after SSH Login**

Before everyone thinks my IPv6 network isn't properly configured here are a few proofs otherwise:

1. If I SSH to the machine right after the boot and try to use `ping6` it works:

   ```
   server.example:~# ping6 -I 2a04:-----::242 test-ping-host.example -c 5
   PING test-ping-host.example(test-ping-host.example) from 2a04:-----::242 : 56 data bytes
   64 bytes from test-ping-host.example: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=7.41 ms
   64 bytes from test-ping-host.example: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=7.41 ms
   64 bytes from test-ping-host.example: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=7.31 ms
   ^C
   --- test-ping-host.example ping statistics ---
   3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 7.314/7.381/7.415/0.047 ms
   ```
2. If I restart, for instance, `lighttpd` it binds correctly to the IPv6 it supposed to and I can open hosted websites using a IPv6 client or `ping6` from another machine.

---

**Here is my question**: Is this normal? Shouldn't the IPv6 also work because `systemd-networkd-wait-online` made sure it was available? Or... does `at least one link to gain a carrier.` really mean that after I get an working IPv4 it will stop waiting and the IPv6 addresses are still not routable? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I'm actually right, it's not waiting for IPv6. I posted this issue on the project's Github and someone marked it as an RFE: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2037

Check this for a solution (disabling IPv6 DAD) that temporally fixes the issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/766253/ensure-systemd-wait-for-ipv6-before-start-service-unit