# How to delay postfix start on raspbian?

Tags: postfix, raspbian

Running postfix 2.11.3 on Raspbian 8 (jesse) and seeing the same problem described here:

[Postfix does not send mails until the service is restarted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219567/postfix-does-not-send-mails-until-the-service-is-restarted)

I want to try postponing startup of postfix until after the network is up. But the command suggested in the comments `/sbin/chkconfig --level 345 postfix on` doesn't work on raspbian.

Can someone tell me the best way to postpone startup of postfix on Raspbian?

Comment: I've tried disabling IPv6 using the advice found here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45974

But that didn't seem to help.